# Performance issues when copying the first N columns of table A to table B using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

**Context**

I have `A`and `B` tables where `A` has `m` columns, while `B` has `n` columns. Tables share the first `columnCount` columns. I need to copy data in `columnCount` columns from `B` to `A`.

I have no control on the structure of tables `A` and `B`.

**Problem**

My code is working, however I have performance issues. Indeed, if `A` has 730 lines (and 182 columns), and `B` has 470 lines (and 61 columns), and if I need to copy the content of the first 25 columns, it currently takes ~8 minutes to achieve the copy (~1 sec per line.)

**Question**

How can I modify my code / algorithm in order to speed up the copy ?

**My code**

```
' prior to executing the code, calculation, screen updating, animations, events 
' and alerts areturned off
.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
.ScreenUpdating = False
.EnableAnimations = False
.EnableEvents = False
.DisplayAlerts = False


' creates a sub range of a range keeping only the first columnCount columns 
' of the original range
Function subRange(r As Range, columnCount As Integer) As Range
    Set subRange = r.Resize(1, columnCount)
End Function

' adds data of the first columnCount columns of a sourceTableName to a targetTableName
Public Sub addDataToTable(targetWkbook As Workbook, targetSheetName, _
                targetTableName As String, sourceWkbook As Workbook, _
                sourceSheetName As String, sourceTableName As String, _
                columnCount As Integer)
    Dim table As ListObject
    Set table = sourceWkbook.Sheets(sourceSheetName).ListObjects(sourceTableName)

    Dim currentRow As ListRow
    For Each currentRow In table.ListRows
        addDataRow targetWkbook, targetSheetName, targetTableName, _
                 subRange(currentRow.Range, columnCount), columnCount
    Next
End Sub

' adds a data row to a table, only filling the first columnCount columns
Sub addDataRow(wkbook As Workbook, sheetName, tableName As String, NewData As Range, _
               columnCount As Integer)
    Dim table As ListObject
    Set table = wkbook.Sheets(sheetName).ListObjects(tableName)

    Dim lastRow As Range

    'First check if the last table row is empty; if not, add a row
    If table.ListRows.Count > 0 Then
        Set lastRow = subRange(table.ListRows(table.ListRows.Count).Range, columnCount)
        If Application.CountBlank(lastRow) < lastRow.Columns.Count Then
            table.ListRows.Add
        End If
    End If

    'Copy NewData to new table row only filling columnCount columns 
    Set lastRow = subRange(table.ListRows(table.ListRows.Count).Range, columnCount)
    lastRow.Value2 = NewData.Value2
End Sub
```

Comment: If you want to speed up your code try not to use `.Copy` method, and instead set the values to each other. In simple terms `tb1.value = tb2.value`. But I think this post is more geared for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @DeanDeVilliers The posted code does not use `.Copy`. I agree with the Code Review part though

Comment: You are moving a lot if (potentially) heavy objects between your UDF's. I understand the need to keep UDF's small but you have to get the balance right. Try an amalgamate your code into 1 UDF and give that a go

Answer (score 2):

As one of the comments states, your procedure is overly complicated and passing a lot of variables back and forth. I consolidated your procedure into one (it's simple enough to not be split up into three separate procedures anyway):

```
Public Sub addDataToTable(targetWkbook As Workbook, targetSheetName As String, targetTableName As String, sourceWkbook As Workbook, sourceSheetName As String, sourceTableName As String, columnCount As Integer)

Dim table As ListObject
Set table = sourceWkbook.Sheets(sourceSheetName).ListObjects(sourceTableName)

Dim target_table As ListObject
Set target_table = targetWkbook.Sheets(targetSheetName).ListObjects(targetTableName)

Dim currentRow As ListRow
Dim lastrow As Range, NewData As Range
Dim lastEmpty As Boolean

lastEmpty = True
Set lastrow = target_table.ListRows(target_table.ListRows.Count).Range.Resize(1, columnCount)
If target_table.ListRows.Count > 0 And Application.CountBlank(lastrow) < lastrow.Columns.Count Then lastEmpty = False


For Each currentRow In table.ListRows
    Set NewData = currentRow.Range.Resize(1, columnCount)

    If Not lastEmpty Then
        target_table.ListRows.Add
    Else
        lastEmpty = False
    End If

    Set lastrow = target_table.ListRows(target_table.ListRows.Count).Range.Resize(1, columnCount)

    lastrow.Value2 = NewData.Value2
Next

End Sub
```

You also don't need a separate function that essentially performs `.Resize`, just use `.Resize` in the first place. Also, you only need to check if the `lastrow` is empty once, after that you keep writing into the `lastrow` so it will never be empty. Try the code above and see how it handles your data.

Comment: I tested this code on some sample data and it adds a new row for every new row of data. Are you sure you used the exact code I provided?

Comment: Side note: by merging the UDF, I gained 6.9 seconds on a process that takes around 637 seconds (1.1% gain). The `addDataRow` `sub` being used by various other subs, the performance gain is in my opinion not worth the copy paste / readability loss. However getting rid of the `subRange` `Sub` made me gain additional 20 seconds (for a total gain of 4.5%.) It's still slow but it's a bit faster.

Comment: Huh, I was hoping that removing stuff like `.CountBlank` from the loop would make more of a difference. If you step through the code with `F8`, which lines take the biggest amount of time?

Comment: I removed my previous comment about the algorithm (sorry i am tired). The line which takes the biggest amount of time is the one that adds a line to the table...

Comment: Are you working with `True` tables? some people refer to a range as a table.. gets a bit confusing

Comment: @Zac these are true tables yes.